# Missing artifact spring-webmvc:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.6.RELEASE

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, pom.xml

I am very much new to the world of Java, Spring.
Building my first Maven project today with loads of issues. 
I'm unable to get my pom.xml working.

this is the auto XML built in my eclipse and using Maven, Dynamic Web Project.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.bapu</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVCDemo</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringMVCDemo Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>spring-webmvc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet-api</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringMVCDemo</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself (see [mcve]). Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and will most likely not be answered. **For more Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 0):

updated the 4.0.6 to the available version 4.0.3 as per the jars list in WEB-INF\lib folder.
It worked perfect.

Comment: were you using Intellij IDEA